# Server side paging in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, row-number

I am a little confused about how SQL server achieves less reads and performance improvements using common table expressions and ROW_NUMBER. Why doesn't the table actualized in the expression have to perform all the reads which a normal query would have to perform to allow the query to order using ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: What other solution are you comparing with?

Comment: Essentially just a query which doesn't page using rownumber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CTE` is not (necessarily) "actualized". It's not that it will inevitably copy all rows elsewhere and will perform other operations over the copy (though it may behave so it the optimizer decides it's better).

If we take this simple query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn BETWEEN 101 AND 110
```

and look at its plan we'll see something like this:

```
  |--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1003]>=(101) AND [Expr1003]<=(110)))
       |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:(CASE WHEN (110) IS NULL OR (110)<(0) THEN (0) ELSE (110) END))
            |--Sequence Project(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=row_number))
                 |--Segment
                      |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([ee].[dbo].[mytable].[PK__mytable__3213E83F29C2D227]), ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Here, the records are scanned (in `id` order as the table is clustered on `id`), assigned the `ROW_NUMBER` (this is what `Sequence Project` does) and passed on to `TOP` which just halts execution when a certain threshold is reached (`110` records in our case).

Those 110 records are passed to `Filter` which only passes the records with `rn` greater than 100.

The query itself only scans `110` records:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 10)
Table 'mytable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

in 3 pages.

Now let's see the unpaginated query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        id
```

This one is pretty simple: read everything from the table and spit it out.

```
  |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([ee].[dbo].[mytable].[PK__mytable__3213E83F29C2D227]), ORDERED FORWARD)
```

However, looking easily does not mean done easily. The table is quite large and we need to do many a read to return all records:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(строк обработано: 1310720)
Table 'mytable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2765, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 266 ms,  elapsed time = 11690 ms.
```

So, in a nutshell, the pagination query just knows when to stop.

Comment: Would this still be the case where the query is ordered by, for example, a calculated field? e.g. in our case we have a set of results which are ordered by proximity to a location. In order to order and paginate the results correctly, it seems that each record would have to be evaluated.

Comment: @MatthewEvans: if you want to order by proximity you would need to use spatial indexes. Unfortunately, they don't work that well in SQL Server so it's better to use own tiling algorithm.

Comment: Yes - we tried the Geography types and experienced performance issues. So we use our own user defined distance function.