# C# dataGridView select 100 by 100 rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, fetch

I have a problem with dataGridView in C#. I want to select 100 by 100 rows of data. The table is very big with 100000 rows and growing. So if i select all rows it takes too long to fill the dataGridView.

So on start i would select 100 rows, and when the user comes to the 100 row it has to select 100 another rows, when he comes to 200 row, another 100 and so on...

Now i'm doing this like:

```
SELECT a.vz_id, a.ste_rac_nal, a.ste_pak, a.dat_pak, A.ISO20022_53_VALID, A.ISO20022_53_IZPISEK
                FROM VZ_IZPISKI a
                where rownum < 100
                order by A.VZ_ID desc
```

If you don't understand what i mean please comment

Comment: have fun http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445504.aspx

Comment: You can look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334799/using-a-background-worker-update-a-progressbar-on-the-progress-of-a-recursive

Comment: @Marko Leben: So are you want ask about SQL or the way working on Window forms? or asp.net?

Comment: Tnx its called paging. I didn't found the word in english.

Comment: If about SQL paging at server side. Look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384540/server-side-paging-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement paging on server side. You should only return the data that user is viewing currently. It will increase responsiveness of your application as well.

Comment: OK i'll try. tnx for your answer